# Weighted Probabilities

Tags: probability

With numpy, how would I select an item with weighted probability?

```
items = [["Item 1", 0.7],
["Item 2", 0.2],
["Item 3", 0.1]]

selected_item = select_item(items).
```

The chances of selecting "Item 1" should be 0.7 and "Item 2" 0.2 ...

Comment: Have a look at `numpy.random.choice` and the parameter `p` which can be used to set the probability weights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[numpy.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) would work:

```
from numpy.random import choice

items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
choice(items, p=[0.7, 0.2, 0.1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application, you might or might not want to build a large pre-calculated list, or even a generator to do this.

An advantage of a large pre-calculated list might be speed if selecting one object randomly over and over is slowing you down.

Here are a few ways, including two functions `select_item_1(items)` and `select_item_2(items)`. I always like to write a script that does what I need myself, before turning to an existing method. It's good practice and it helps me understand what that method might be doing internally.

Also included is use of `numpy.random.choice` as [suggested by @Oxbowerce](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/100573/weighted-probabilities#comment104952_100573)

For the two functions I've run them n times and printed the results. I added a fourth item so that the weights don't necessarily sum to 1 so that I remember to renormalize them correctly.

```
group 1 [('Item 1', 4653), ('Item 2', 1332), ('Item 3', 666), ('Item 4', 3349)]
group 2 [('Item 1', 4637), ('Item 2', 1345), ('Item 3', 658), ('Item 4', 3360)]
group 3 [('Item 1', 4675), ('Item 2', 1336), ('Item 3', 649), ('Item 4', 3340)]
group 4 [('Item 1', 4733), ('Item 2', 1342), ('Item 3', 604), ('Item 4', 3321)]
```

Script:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random, choice

def select_item_1(items):
    i, v = zip(*items) 
    a = np.cumsum(v)
    r = a.max() * random()
    j = np.argmax(a > r)
    return i[j]

def select_item_2(items):
    i, v = zip(*items)
    vn = np.array(v) / sum(v) 
    return choice(a=i, size=1, p=n)

def count_them(group):
    dic = dict()
    for thing in group:
        try:
            dic[thing] += 1
        except:
            dic[thing] = 1
    return dic

items = [["Item 1", 0.7], ["Item 2", 0.2], ["Item 3", 0.1], ["Item 3", 0.5]]

n = 10000

# get a list of n items selected randomly using weights
item_list, values = zip(*items)
values_norm = np.array(values) / sum(values) 
a = np.cumsum(values)
r = a.max() * random(n)
j = [np.argmax(a > x) for x in r]
group_1 = [item_list[x] for x in j]


group_2 = [select_item_1(items) for i in range(n)]

group_3 = choice(a=item_list, size=n, p=values_norm)

group_4 = [choice(a=item_list, size=1, p=values_norm)[0] for i in range(n)]

groups = (group_1, group_2, group_3, group_4)

for i, group in enumerate(groups):
    print('group', i+1, sorted(count_them(group).items()))
```